# Can only get One item in foreach PHP

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I only get one item on my foreach even i have more than one item to loop.
This is my codes:

```
$sql = "Select vID from info";
$stmt = $db->query($sql);  
$users = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$dataArray = array();
foreach($users as $user){
 $item =  $user['vID']
 $dataArray['ids'] = $item
}
echo json_encode($dataArray);
```

This is the data fetch from database:

```
[
  {
    "vidID": "1234"
  },
  {
    "vidID": "5678"
  }
]
```

And when i tried to echo my created array, only one item return:

```
{
  "vids": "5678"
}
```

Comment: you overwrite the value in your foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks @Dagon for letting me know...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you're overriding the id in the array instead of appending.

If you want to append it to the array, replace

```
$dataArray['ids'] = $item;
```

With

```
$dataArray[] = $item;
```

Or

```
array_push($dataArray, $item);
```